# Android compiler: Cannot resolve symbol string

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, intellij-idea

When I try to add a strServerIP to the class Server, I get a:
Cannot resolve symbol string
compiler error.

Why?

```
package com.example;


public class Server
{
    //public static java.lang.string SERVERIP;
    public static android.R.string SERVERIP;
    public static java.lang.string strServerIP = "monster.idsoftware.com";
    public static string strServerIP = "monster.idsoftware.com";
    public static int SERVERPORT = 27950;
    public static int PROTOCOL = 68;
}
```

Comment: Why strServerIP is defined twice?

Comment: lose the hungarian prefixes on strServerIp. With java the type is always next to the variable so its redundant to include in the variable name, and duplication is a sin in software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use "String" not "string"

Comment: Oh lol, damnit, I knew Java is case-sensitive, but as somebody else already said: "it's 'almost' like C". The almost is unfortunate.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to RickNotFred's answer, `android.R.string` is not a data type, and you are using it as such in the first line of your `Server` implementation.

If you are new to Java, I definitely recommend spending some weeks learning Java outside of Android. Android's use of Java is just strange enough that some people seem to get frustrated learning both at the same time. Also, books on Java will not have Android in mind, and books on Android pretty much assume you already know Java.

Comment: actually, I'm writing a UDP client to query the ID Software master server. It won't be easy, but I'll survive.